# How to import unusual data formats into R?

Tags: r, import

Format consist of lines, every line has set of key="value" elements.

Format example:

```
X="1" Y="2" Z="who are you?"
Y="4" Z="bla bla..."
X="42"
```

I would like to import this data into R, table or data.frame, where key defines column.

Comment: How are records (rows) defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code parses the file you provided in a 'melted' form:

```
data<-NULL 
stream<-file("path");open(stream) #or stream<- textConnection(' X="1" Y="2" Z="who are you?" Y="4" Z="bla bla..." X="42"')
while(length(ele<-c(scan(stream,what="string",n=1,sep="="),scan(stream,what="string",n=1,sep=" ")))>0){
    data<-rbind(data,ele);
}
close(stream);
print(data);
```

Now crystallizing:

```
 sapply(unique(data[,1]),function(key) data[data[,1]==key,2])
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks!
Can you give some hint how to speed this up? It took about 20min to read 40k lines, maybe because of many IO operations to HDD? I think that reading whole file into string and than parse it should improve performance?

Comment: And one other question, final data structure is ok for some things, but i would like to have data in some other format, where row coincidence is conserved?

Comment: About speed, it could go faster if you would replace "="s with " "s; than everything could be read as a series of space separated strings by one scan(stream,what="string",sep=" "). 
About conserving rows, can you write more about the structure of this file and how do you want to represent it in R? And I think a new question will be suitable for that.